# Naive question about manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I was trying to understand the definition of a manifold. This question arised: is every manifold $M$ the inverse image of some $\Delta : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. The implicit function theorem, i understand, only says that yes, this indeed, holds, as long as the point of which the inverse image of $\Delta$ is calculated is regular.

Is the above statement true, or should state that "...every manifold is the inverse image of some family $\Delta_i...$"

One characteristic that I find in both the $S^1$ and $S^2$ (the only ones I can visualize) is that they can both be defined as the inverse image of a unique $\Delta$! What I want to understand is how a manifold would look if it were the inverse image of multiple functions $\Delta$. Would it have peculiar topological properties?

Comment: The inverse image of what? Of a point?

Comment: Yes, a point in the codomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Note that such a (sub)manifold would have codimension 1 in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example $\mathbb{RP}^2$ does not embed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (for a rigourous proof see M.W.Hirsh, *Differential Topology*, chapter 4). But this counter example requires some tools so your question is not naive at all !

For another similar counter example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188717/p1-not-a-regular-level-surface-of-a-c1-function-on-p2).

Comment: The reason that it doesn't embed can be more subtle than merely topological? I'll have a look at Hirsch. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: It comes from a more general theorem: A compact nonorientable $n$-manifold without boundary cannot be embedded in a simply connected $(n + 1)$-manifold. The idea is that codimension 1 is to small

Comment: If you do not assume that the submanifold  is the preimage of a regular value (and the question does not appear have this requirement) then of course, you can realize every manifold this way. Even more: Every closed subset in $R^n$ is the preimage of $0$ under some continuous function.